# How to add keystore file by using jmeter library in Java code

Tags: java, jmeter, ssl-certificate, keystore

Like I have tried adding ***keystore.jks*** file in jmeter application by heading over to **Options > SSL manager >** there choose .**jks** file and at run time we need to give **password/passphrase** for that file and it will work, like same way I'm trying to mimic similar thing using jmeter library in Java, but couldn't find any alternative in doing so.

like is there any way to add .jks file through Java code using jmeter library so that to achieve similar thing which I did in jmeter application?

this is what i tried using jmeter library for java, **ALIAS_VALUE, ENDPOINT_VALUE, CONTENT_PATH_VALUE, API_KEY_VALUE are used to mask the original value for security concerns**.

```
StandardJMeterEngine jmeterEngine = new StandardJMeterEngine();
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("C:/Users/pmaiya/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/apache-jmeter-5.2.1");
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("C:/Users/pmaiya/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:/Users/pmaiya/Documents/Zoom/identity.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "123456");

        HashTree testPlanHashTree = new HashTree();




        JmeterKeyStore.getInstance("JKS").load(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/pmaiya/Documents/Zoom/identity.jks"), "123456");
        JmeterKeyStore.DEFAULT_ALIAS_VAR_NAME.contentEquals("ALIAS_VALUE");

        JmeterKeyStore.getInstance("JKS", 0, -1, "test").load(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/pmaiya/Documents/Zoom/identity.jks"), "123456");


       SSLManager.getInstance().configureKeystore(true, 0, -1, "ALIAS_VALUE");
       SSLManager.isSSLSupported();





        // create http sampler
        HTTPSamplerProxy httpSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
        httpSampler.setProtocol("HTTPS");
        httpSampler.setDomain("ENDPOINT_VALUE");
        httpSampler.setPath("CONTEXT_PATH_VALUE");
        httpSampler.setMethod("GET");
        httpSampler.setName("get call");
        httpSampler.setFollowRedirects(true);
        httpSampler.setAutoRedirects(false);
        httpSampler.setUseKeepAlive(true);
        httpSampler.setEnabled(true);
        httpSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSampler.class.getName());
        httpSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());


        HeaderManager manager = new HeaderManager();
        manager.setEnabled(true);
        manager.add(new Header("apikey", "API_KEY_VALUE"));
        manager.add(new Header("Content-Type", "application/json"));
        manager.setName("headermanager"); 
        manager.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HeaderManager.class.getName());
        manager.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HeaderPanel.class.getName());





        LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
        loopController.setLoops(1);
        loopController.setFirst(true);
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
        loopController.initialize();

        //create thread group
        ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
        threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
        threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
        threadGroup.setName("get");
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

        //create test plan
        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan();
        testPlan.setEnabled(true);
        testPlan.setName("Test Plan");
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
        testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());



        //Add sampler to the thread group


        HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanHashTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
        threadGroupHashTree.add(httpSampler);
       threadGroupHashTree.add(manager);



        // Generating the JMX file
        SaveService.saveTree(testPlanHashTree, new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/pmaiya/Desktop/TestSSL.jmx"));
        jmeterEngine.configure(testPlanHashTree);
        jmeterEngine.run();            
         System.out.println("executed successfully");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your keystore contains only one certificate which you need to use for client-side encryption - setting `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` and `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword`, just make sure to call these functions:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:/Users/pmaiya/Documents/Zoom/identity.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "123456");
```

**before this line**

```
JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("C:/Users/pmaiya/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/jmeter.properties");
```

If your keystore contains >1 certificate and you would like each JMeter virtual user to use its own certificate - go for [Keystore Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration) (the relevant JMeter API class name is [org.apache.jmeter.config.KeystoreConfig](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/KeystoreConfig.html)) like it's described in [How to Use Multiple Certificates When Load Testing Secure Websites article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-multiple-certificates-when-load-testing-secure-websites)

Comment: Thank you like for single it worked for me, trying for multiple keystore files.

Comment: Is there any working example how to use multiple .jks files in java? please provide it would be helpful, thanks @DmitriT